# Blur part of the image with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to blur a part of the photo. My code is as follows:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};
var drag = false;
var imageObj = null;

function init() {
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { drag = false; }

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        ctx.filter = 'blur(5px)';

    }
}
//
init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

I draw a rectangle but I want to apply the blur filter only on that rectangle not to the whole image as it is now. Any idea how to do that?

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmr50kcf/1/)

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to blur part of an image in JS or CSS. One solution would be to have two images on top of each other, one blurred, one not. Then you can display the blurred one in the cropped area you draw the rectangle.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is not possible to create a blurry rectangle? Now I have rectangle with border and without background and I want that the rectangle is blur.

Comment: An idea could be to draw another image inside the rectangle drawn by dragging the cursor and shift it to make it overlap the first one (with an hidden overflow) and blur that one

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using `HTML5 Canvas`

I have made a fiddle to blur the part `350` from image.
Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/k6aaqdx6/3/

## Edit:

updated according to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tbjLk6eu/2

Code that I added:

```
imgData=ctx.getImageData(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.filter = 'none';
ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
ctx.putImageData(imgData,rw, rh);
ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
```

Comment: Just an FYI, the above code puts the canvas element in the place of image

Comment: note: I am working on a secure environment and your image wasn't loading make sure to update the SRC

Comment: Here is the proper working fiddle according to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/tbjLk6eu/2/

Comment: The problem is if I draw the rectangle and if I click outside the blur doesn't dissapear.

Comment: That wasn't the part of your question. also I see no coding attempt for it in your original fiddle.

Comment: Do you see my fiddle? It works fine, I just want to blur the rectangle, nothing else needs to change.

Comment: Yes, and the blur inside the rectangle is happening.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Safari? Works great on Chrome, but not Safari?

Answer (score 1):

working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zoh5o9p5/

If you use a base64 image and do some changes it will work as you expected

made some changes in mouseMove function.

```
function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {

        ctx.filter = 'blur(5px)';
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

        if(rect.w>0 && rect.h>0)
        {
            imgDrow=ctx.getImageData(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.filter = 'none';
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

        w=rect.w<0?rect.startX+rect.w:rect.startX; 
        h=rect.h<0?rect.startY+rect.h:rect.startY;
        if(imgDrow)
        {
            ctx.putImageData(imgDrow,w, h);
        }
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);

    }
```

working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zoh5o9p5/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Safari? Works great on Chrome, but not Safari?

Answer (score 0):

we can use fabric.js library. Here you can draw a rectangle and move it and resize it. The original fiddle was having some console error and scaling was not working. I have resolved them all in the bellow jsfiddle.

Here we first copy the original image and create a copy canvas and make the full image blur. Then on move or scaling of the rectangle just showing actual crop to show the proper blur section.
[image]

```
function blurSelection(left=0, top=0, img=null) {
  if (img) {
    img.cropX = left;
    img.cropY = top;
    fabricCanvas.renderAll();
  } else {
    const image = fabric.Image.fromURL(blurredCanvas.toDataURL(), function (img) {
      img.cropX = left;
      img.cropY = top;
      img.width = 200; // Default
      img.height = 100; // Default
      img.objectCaching = false;
      fabricCanvas.add(img);
      img.bringToFront();
      img.on('moving', function (options) {
        const newLeft = options.target.left;
        const newTop = options.target.top;
        blurSelection(newLeft, newTop, img=options.target);
      });

      img.on('scaling', function (options) {
        const newLeft = options.target.left;
        const newTop = options.target.top;
        const newWidth = options.target.width * options.target.scaleX;
        const newHeight = options.target.height *  options.target.scaleY;
                    //console.log("scaleX",options.target.scaleX,'scaleY',options.target.scaleX,"newWidth",newWidth,"newHeight",newHeight)
        options.target.scaleX=1;
        options.target.scaleY=1;
        options.target.width=newWidth;
        options.target.height=newHeight;
      })
    });
  }
}

function copyCanvas() {
  const objects = fabricCanvas.getObjects();
  const copiedCanvas = fabricCanvas.toCanvasElement();

  const blurredImage = new fabric.Image(copiedCanvas);

  const filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Blur({
    blur: 0.8
  });
  blurredImage.filters.push(filter);
  blurredImage.applyFilters();

  blurredCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(copiedCanvas);
  window.blurredCanvas = blurredCanvas;
  blurredCanvas.add(blurredImage);
  blurredCanvas.renderAll();

  // Just for the inspection of the blurred image
  document.getElementById('asd').src = copiedCanvas.toDataURL();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/debchy/ajbpefk4/7/